Define standard basis of a quadratic form
Let $Q:V\rightarrow V$ be a non-degenerate quadratic form on a $\mathbb{F}$-vector space $V$, where $\mathbb{F}=\mathbb{F}_q$, $q=p^f$.
Recall that this means that
$$Q(\lambda v)=\lambda^2Q(v), \text{ for all } v \in V \text{ and } \lambda \in \mathbb{F},$$
and that $Q$ is endowed with an associated bilinear form $(\cdot,\cdot)_Q$ defined as
$$(u,v)_Q=Q(u+v)-Q(u)-Q(v).$$
Following the book of Kleidman and Liebeck, Proposition 2.5.3, if $dimV=2m$, then the space $(V,Q)$ has a basis of one of the following forms:

$\mathcal{B}^{+}=(e_1,f_1,\dots,e_m,f_m)$, where
$Q^{+}(e_i)=Q^{+}(f_i)=0, \hspace{5mm}(e_i,f_j)=\delta_{ij}$.
$\mathcal{B}^{-}=(e_1,f_1,\dots,e_m,f_m,x_m,y_m)$, where
$Q^{-}(e_i)=Q^{-}(f_i)=(e_i,x_m)=(f_i,x_m)=(e_i,y_m)=(f_i,y_m)=0, \text{ }$
$(e_i,f_j)=\delta_{ij}, \text{ }Q^{-}(x_m)=Q^{-}(y_m)=1, \text{ }(x_m,y_m)=\zeta^2+\zeta^{-2},$ with $\zeta \in \mathbb{F}_{q^2} \setminus\mathbb{F}_{q}$ satisfying $\zeta^{q+1}=0$.

Shouldn't also be included in the definitions that $(e_i,e_j)=(f_i,f_j)=0$? Otherwise, how can I get these relations?

Yes, Proposition 2.5.3 in Kleidman and Liebeck is missing the relations $(e_i,e_j) =  (f_i,f_j) = 0$ for all $i$ and $j$.
Note that on the next page (p.28), they write that $\langle e_1, \ldots, e_m \rangle$ is a totally singular subspace in 2.5.3i, 2.5.3iii, and $\langle e_1, \ldots, e_{m-1} \rangle$ is a totally singular subspace in 2.5.3ii.
So the assumption $(e_i,e_j) = (f_i,f_j) = 0$ is intended by Kleidman and Liebeck, and it is also what they prove.

Thank you very much!
